# Why is a sum statement so bizarrely synthesized?

Tags: matlab, vhdl, hdl-coder

I have 4 buttons on an FPGA dev board so I wrote

```
function [HEX0] = Bar(KEY)
  n = uint8(sum(KEY, 'native'));
  ...
```

Unfortunately, HDL Coder turned it into the following chunk of VHDL:

```
y := '0';

FOR k IN 0 TO 3 LOOP
  y := y OR KEY(k);
END LOOP;

y_0 := '0' & '0' & '0' & '0' & '0' & '0' & '0' & y;
```

Which I just don't get. Can you help me figure out what's going on here?

Comment: If this is really related to Matalb, can you tell how, or give more context?

Comment: @LuisMendo I'm not sure what you're asking. The top code is MATLAB. The bottom is what MALTAB's HDL Coder gives me.

Comment: @DmitriNesteruk: Some example input (including data types) and the expected behaviour is always useful. I'm not sure if your m-code really implements what you want.

Comment: @DmitriNesteruk Sorry, my bad. I had never seen the `'native'` option to `sum`; that's what was confusing me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To understand this, you have to understand the matlab `sum` with logical inputs and native option. The sum of logicals is a logical. Thus `sum` could be replaced with an `or`

```
sum([true,true],'native')
```

And this is exactly what your Coder puts out. The for-Loop implements the sum (`sum(KEY, 'native')`), where the coder recognizes that it could be implemented using a OR.

Finally, conversion from logical to uint8 is done padding 7 zero bits.

Comment: Thanks, I get it now. I guess I must need `double` instead of `native`, right?

Comment: @DmitriNesteruk: `n = sum(uint8(KEY), 'native');` The native sum of uint8 is again a uint8. If you want the sum of all active ports, this is the simplest solution. I don't know what your target system is, but maybe you should avoid doubles.